# Databricks runtime from docker hub image vs original Databricks runtime

Tags: docker, databricks

are databricks runtimes from docker hub ( https://hub.docker.com/r/databricksruntime/standard ) same as actual runtimes inside Databricks? I mean when we made our own docker image from databricksruntime/standard will be there same dependencies, versions etc as in runtime inside databricks? We need to archive older runtimes in bank environment and be able to run old notebooks with exactly same runtime.

And another question about runtime’s version. If I use my docker container in cluster creation with for example runtime version 6.6 but in setup I also select different version in column Databricks runtime version what will happened? Will be column Databricks runtime version ignored?

[runtime version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4i24.jpg)

[runtime version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UsGw.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The base Docker images that are published on Docker Hub are just a base Docker images - they don't contain actual Databricks Runtime (DBR). DBR is actually injected into Docker image (base or provided by you) on a start.  And you can really create a completely new Docker image, not based on the Databricks' base images - you just need to [meet requirements](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/custom-containers.html#option-2-build-your-own-docker-base) for Java version, some tools, etc.

Comment: So if I made docker image based on this https://hub.docker.com/r/databricksruntime/standard  it will not be actual Databricks Runtime (DBR)? It contains only dependencies (scala,java,python etc.)? Is that mean I'm still dependent on Databricks to not delete old runtime?
Only way is to make my own Databricks' base images?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't contain actual Spark code. If you walk the chain, you will reach the `minimal` docker image (https://github.com/databricks/containers/blob/master/ubuntu/minimal/Dockerfile) that is just based on the Ubuntu... You can reach Support to get clarification about removal of the runtimes.

Comment: How to run Python Notebook from the repo above?